# bootstrap 4 modal problem with leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, bootstrap-modal

I have problem with leaflet map when I use it in bootstrap 4 modal.

Map do not render correctly, and I don't know how to fix it.

this is my map script:

```
var url = 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
var attr = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    osm = L.tileLayer(url, {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: attr
    });
var map = L.map('mapId').setView([35.6892, 51.3890], 10).addLayer(osm);
map.on('click', onMapClick);
var markers = [];
function onMapClick(e) {
    var geojsonFeature = {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng]
        }
    }
    if (markers.length > 0) {
        map.removeLayer(markers.pop());
    }
    var marker;
    document.getElementById('latitude').value = e.latlng.lat;
    document.getElementById('longitude').value = e.latlng.lng;
    L.geoJson(geojsonFeature, {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            marker = L.marker(e.latlng, {
                riseOnHover: true,
                draggable: true,
            });
            markers.push(marker);
            return marker;
        }
    }).addTo(map);
}
```

I am looking for a solution to fix it::

This is my bootstrap modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mapModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mapModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="mapModalLabel">انتخاب موقعیت مکانی ملک از روی نقشه:</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="mapId"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">ثبت</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the modal code? Where do you call it?

Comment: i edited my post

Comment: could you provide a fiddle? then i could try to fix your problem. ;)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n1zsfdue/

Comment: @jsadev.net So why didn't you solve the problem? Almost 5 years have passed

Comment: @AliRezaAbbasian he/she already solved it. take a look at the answer. thats the reason why i did nothing. :) The problem was that the map has been rendered insdie a hidden html element. the only two ways to fix it, is to render the map only if the modal is visible, or to run map.invalidateSize() if the modal gets into view.

Answer (score 4):

I found it:

```
<script>
    $('#mapModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
            map.invalidateSize();
        }, 10);
    });
</script>
```